# Give a complete list of ternary cyclic code of length 3.

Tags: coding-theory

> Give a complete list of ternary cyclic code of length 3.

For $x^3-1\in\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. Generator polynomials of ternary code of length $3$ are $\{1,x-1,x^2+x+1,x^3-1\}$, these generator polynomials generates 
\begin{align*}
  \langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle&=\mathbb{F}_3^3\\
  \langle\langle x-1\rangle\rangle&=\{(0,0,0),(2,1,0),(0,2,1),(1,0,2)\}\\
  \langle\langle x^2+x+1\rangle\rangle&=\{(0,0,0),(1,1,1)\}\\
  \langle\langle x^3-1\rangle\rangle&=\{0,0,0\}
\end{align*}

Can anyone check this solution? I am not sure this is right or not?

---

**EDIT:**

$\langle\langle x-1\rangle\rangle=\{(0,0,0),(2,1,0),(0,2,1),(2,0,2),(0,2,2),(2,2,0),(1,2,0),(0,1,2),(2,0,1)\}$

I got 9 codewords, but I don't have $(1,0,2)$.

$\langle\langle x^2+x+1\rangle\rangle=\{(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2)\}$

Comment: I think you are forgetting the codewords generated by $g(x) \times 2$ (and its shifts). REmeber that a cyclic code is linear.

Comment: @leonbloy you are right, do I need codewords generate by $g(x)\times x+1$?

Comment: Let $g$ be the degree of the generator polynomial; that equals the redundancy : $g=n-k$. The size of the codebook is $3^{k}=3^{3-g}$. The shifts of the polynomial gives you the rows of the generator matrix. You need to list all the $3^{k}$ linear combinations of those rows.

Comment: @leonbloy I think I made a mistake. Does $x^3=2$?